# Facebook PHP SDK get page posts data is empty

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a strange problem with the Facebook PHP SDK,

```
$response = $this->getConnection()->get("me/posts");
$feedEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
var_dump($response); exit;
```

*the `getConnection()` call provides me with a `\Facebook\Facebook` object with the `default_access_token` set but this works as I get a response from Facebook*

But the body from the above `var_dump` gives:

```
["decodedBody":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["data"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
```

What is really strange is when I use the [Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) (as my Application and using the same Page) I see all the posts. So I thought maybe it was the access token was not working correctly so I copied and pasted the access token shown in from the graph explorer into my `get()` call to override the default like below unfortunately this did not work and I got exactly the same output.

```
$response = $this->getConnection()->get("me/posts", "EAA....");
$feedEdge = $response->getGraphEdge();
var_dump($response); exit;
```

[image: Facebook Graph display using my App and Access Token]

So I'm unsure why the same token in one place would get the information when in another it would get an empty set the worst part is it's not like the Request is failing as that throws an exception it is like Facebook Graph API is reacting differently for my application when using the PHP-SDK verses using the Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after hours of messing around testing stuff in the Graph API Explorer and the API I worked out, there is a problem with `/me/posts` endpoint when using the PHP SDK even if your using a manage_pages `access_token` it seems to lock on to the user that instead of the page unlike the graph explorer that the /me/posts, posts to the entity of the `access_token`.

So make sure to request `/{page_id|user_id}/posts` and it works correctly.